# Необходимо ли обособление словосочетания "по тем или иным причинам?"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Каждый день по тем или иным причинам мы возвращались к нему.

Каждый день мы по тем или иным причинам возвращались к нему.

Зависит ли пунктуация от расположения данного словосочетания в предложении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ни в первом, ни во втором предложении запятые не требуются.
Словосочетание *по тем или иным причинам* не является вводным (в [**списке**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-alphabet) вводных слов и выражений оно отсутствует).
В предложениях нет никаких уточнений или пояснений.

*Кошка абсолютно искренна: человеческие существа **по тем или иным причинам** могут скрывать свои чувства, но кошка — никогда* (Эрнест Хемингуэй).

*Но чудо, явленное Толстым, заключается в том, что он не декларирует эти постулаты, а создает картину мира, в которой мы узнаем самих себя. Вернее, лучшее в себе. Это лучшее **по тем или иным причинам** часто покрывается коростой пошлости* (Л. Н. Таганов. Пора возвращаться к Толстому).

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Нет причин для обособления: это и не вводное сочетание, и не уточняющий оборот.